# Passing Objects from own Model to QTableWidget

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, subclassing, qtablewidget, qlistview

I am trying to do the following in QT, but I'm unsure of how to do it, or even do it efficiently. 
Any input would be greatly appreciated.

I have a QListView and an underlying model that I implemented myself. 
The rows of the model include another class "CJTAGPin" which determine the data.

In the rows of the ListView I only need to display certain elements of this class, which works just fine. 
In the same window, I have a QTableWidget, where i want rows of the Listview to be allowed to dropped.

But in this Widget, the name displayed in the List ist not enough, 
and I would need the instances of "CJJTAGPin" accessible (when pressing a button accessing the cells where Objects were dropped and knowing which instance of CJTAGPin it is).

How can this be achieved? 
I already did some research and found that subclassing QMimeData would be an option, but I'm not quite sure which Class I would need to be subclassing and how to rewrite hasFormat(), formats(), and retrieveData().

Comment: Have you tried searching for these methods/classes on SO? I recall at least one answer where it's shown how to do something like that :)

Comment: [Passing data around with QMimeData in Qt drag and drop] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314078/passing-data-around-with-qmimedata-in-qt-drag-and-drop) Is this the approach I'm looking for?

Comment: Also have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32591384/1329652) where there's a complete implementation of a drop from a model, with requisite decoding of undocumented mime data format.